Fundamental period of a function
For example if a function is like sin(x),cos(x) or sum of some trigonometric functions usually it's not very tough to find its period but what I want to ask is that if we find the period of a function but we aren't sure if it's the fundamental period can we prove it some how ? Another example is that say f(2x+3)+f(2x+7)=1 we can replace x by x+2 and get its period as 8 but we can not confirm that the function's fundamental period is 8 only also sometimes the  functional equation gets complicated and we perform a lot of steps to find its period it won't be easy to confirm its the fundamental period only.(I'm sorry im unable to find that exact question since I had this doubt a few weeks ago and till now I've solved around ≈700 problems from different sources on functions chapter I'm unable to find that exact problem)

Without knowing the function, I doubt it.  $f(x)=\frac 12$ satisfies your condition. As do sin functions where say... $f(w)=\sin \frac {x\pi}4 +\frac 12$ (I think... basically so that $f(2x+3) = \sin \theta + \frac 12$ and $f(2x+7)=\sin (\theta + \pi)+\frac 12$.  I may not have calculated it exactly right).  If $f(x)$ has period $m$ then $g(x)=f(kx)$ will have period $\frac {m}k$.  Not knowing anything else about the function, I think we are doomed.

A smooth function of trig circular functions of same frequency is periodic, so have a definite period.

A period $T$ of a periodic function $f$ is a real number such that $$f(x)=f(x+T)$$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.
There can be multiple periods for one function: for instance, $2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi,\ldots...$ are all periods for the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$.
One usually refers to the period of a function as the smallest of all this values. However, there are functions with no smallest period, such as constant functions or Dirichlet's function: $1_\mathbb{Q}$.

There's NO such thing as FUNDAMENTAL PERIOD.
Ask a specific question. As far as I know, whatever one finds by solving the functional equations, is the smallest interval in which the graph of the function will repeat itself.
